# Windows - Stream screen over network to Smart TV (DLNA)

Tags: streaming, tv

How to live stream Windows screen to DLNA capable Smart TV (Samsung) on the same network?

So far I have found 1 Windows application, that should be able to do this - it's TVersity Screen Server - but it's not working for me.

I have also found other questions on SuperUser regarding this, but none of the answers are actual.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is the best caster that I have found.

You may cast using the three-dot menu icon of Chrome and choose "Cast...".

You will then be presented with the list of all the DLNA devices in your
local network, where you need to select one by a click.
You may toggle the "Sources" drop-down list to be either
"Cast tab" (the default) or "Cast desktop".

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it won't allow me to cast desktop. It discovers the TV, but it says "Available for specific video sites". And when I am on YouTube, it says "Source not supported" for desktop. I have tried some googled tips for that messages, but have not found any solution so far. Do I need chromecast for that? Currently I have only raw Samsung TV with Tizen OS.

Comment: The desktop is truly the desktop, not the same as the screen. If you're looking for screen mirroring, DLNA actually can't do it since it relies on the UPnP protocol which does not support mirroring. Solutions do exist for the Mac, but not for Windows. Third-party applications exist that can cast the screen, but may require Miracast rather than DLNA.

Comment: Yes screen mirroring is the right term, sorry for confusion. I am sure that some third-party applications exist, I just can't find anything that would work. If not using DLNA, then there is for example possibility to screen mirror using Smart View from Android phone, so some Windows app could possibly use the same protocol too (I guess). But if no such app currently exists, I would need to probably get Chromecast. Then the "desktop" cast from Chrome should work, right? The TV model is QE55Q7F and it does not have Miracast.

Comment: Where hardware and software combine, I can't guarantee that Chromecast will work better.

Comment: I understand. Well I will continue to search and hopefully something will come up :) thanks.

Comment: BTW I'm using Chromecast and I think it's an absolutely excellent product.

Comment: I have found a possible way - using TV application "Steam Link" (available on Tizen OS appstore) + Steam running on your PC. It's primarily made for gaming, but can be misussed to stream desktop + sound as well :)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use that open-source software (Universal Media Server).

> Universal Media Server is a free DLNA, UPnP and HTTP/S Media Server. We support all major operating systems, with versions for Windows and Linux.

Then, configure and share the videos folders from your Dashboard at URL
http://localhost:9001/

Download Here: https://github.com/UniversalMediaServer/UniversalMediaServer/releases/download/13.8.1/UMS-13.8.1.exe